# Apex Triggers deletion validation

Tags: trigger

I have a requirement where I want to prevent users to delete Contact if that is associated with Account. I have written a trigger and an apex class for this. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

**Apex Trigger:**

```java
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after Delete, before insert) {

  if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isdelete){
    System.debug('Within trigger.isBefore && trigger.isdelete');
    ContactTriggerHelper.ContactDeletionValidation(Trigger.old);

  }

}
```

**Apex Class:**

```java
Public with sharing class ContactTriggerHelper {

 public static void ContactDeletionValidation(List<Contact> conLst){

 List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, AccountID From Contact where id in:conLst AND AccountId != null];

   contactList[0].addError('An operation is tried to perform to delete the Contact where it is associated with Account');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed out the before delete trigger event:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after Delete, before insert, before delete) {
```

And also, there's no need to query the account, simply check if the AccountId is not null:

```
public static void ContactDeletionValidation(List conLst){
    for (Contact c : conLst) {
        if (c.AccountId != null) {
            c.addError('...');
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest you to check out how to bulkify your trigger in [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) trailhead module.

Comment: On using the above code i am getting the below error:    System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors:

Comment: Did you call the class method `ContactDeletionValidation` in after trigger?

Comment: It is working now. Thanks!